# No logro pasar info de un ListView a otro Activity (ANDROID)

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-listview

luego de mucho tiempo intentando solucionar el problema no me quedo otra mas que recurrir a este medio en donde ojala alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema.
lo que sucede es que intento mandar informacion de una fila de un ListView hacia un nuevo activity en donde hay TextViews en donde podre modificar la info que quede ahi, pero no logro hacer que la info pase del activity Listado al activity Modificar. cuando toco alguna fila la pantalla se pone en blanco y vuelve al Main Activity

LISTADO

```
package com.example.adminclases.appsensor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Listado extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> listado;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            int id = Integer.parseInt(listado.get(i).split(" ")[0]);
            String nombre=listado.get(i).split(" ")[1];
            String usuario=listado.get(i).split(" ")[2];
            String password=listado.get(i).split(" ")[3];
            String correo=listado.get(i).split(" ")[4];
            Intent intent=new Intent(Listado.this,Modificar.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID",id);
            intent.putExtra("NOMBRE",nombre);
            intent.putExtra("USUARIO",usuario);
            intent.putExtra("PASSWORD",password);
            intent.putExtra("CORREO",correo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume () {
    super.onPostResume();
    cargarlistado();
}

private void cargarlistado() {
    listado = ListaPersonas();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listado);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<String> ListaPersonas() {
    ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    BaseHelper helper = new BaseHelper(this, "DEMO", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "Select * from PERSONAS";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String linea = " " + c.getInt(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2) + " " + c.getString(3) + " " + c.getString(4);
            datos.add(linea);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return datos;
}

}
```

MODIFICAR

```
package com.example.adminclases.appsensor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Modificar extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ed_nombre,ed_usuario, ed_password, ed_correo;
Button btn_modificar,btn_eliminar;
int id_recibe;
String nombre_recibe,usuario_recibe, password_recibe, correo_recibe;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_modificar);

ed_nombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_nombre);
ed_usuario=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_usuario);
ed_password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_password);
ed_correo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_correo);
btn_modificar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_modificar);
btn_eliminar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_eliminar);

Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();

if(b!=null)
{
    id_recibe=b.getInt("ID");
    nombre_recibe=b.getString("NOMBRE");
    usuario_recibe=b.getString("USUARIO");
    password_recibe=b.getString("PASSWORD");
    correo_recibe=b.getString("CORREO");
}
ed_nombre.setText(nombre_recibe);
ed_usuario.setText(usuario_recibe);
ed_password.setText(password_recibe);
ed_correo.setText(correo_recibe);


btn_modificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        modificar(id_recibe,ed_nombre.getText().toString(),ed_usuario.getText().toString(),ed_password.getText().toString(),ed_correo.getText().toString());
        onBackPressed();
    }
});

btn_eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        eliminar(id_recibe);
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
}

private void modificar(int id, String nombre, String usuario, String password, String correo)
{
    BaseHelper helper=new BaseHelper(this,"DEMO",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql="UPDATE PERSONAS SET NOMBRE='"+nombre+"', USUARIO='"+usuario+"', PASSWORD='"+password+"', CORREO='"+correo+"' WHERE ID="+id;
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

private void eliminar(int id)
{
    BaseHelper helper=new BaseHelper(this,"DEMO",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql="DELETE FROM PERSONAS WHERE ID="+id;
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
}
```

ACTIVITY_LISTADO.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.adminclases.appsensor.Listado"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ACTIVITY_MODIFICAR.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.adminclases.appsensor.Modificar"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/redondeoedittext"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_weight="0.10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Usuario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="Usuario"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_usuario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/redondeoedittext"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_weight="0.10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/redondeoedittext"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_weight="0.10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Correo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Correo"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed_correo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/redondeoedittext"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_weight="0.10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_modificar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="#649dd9"
    android:hint="Modificar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_eliminar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="#649dd9"
    android:hint="Eliminar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ANDROID MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adminclases.appsensor">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityIngreso" />
    <activity android:name=".Listado" />
    <activity android:name=".Modificar" />
</application>
```

LOGCAT

```
12-05 20:05:23.457 31835-31835/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-05 20:05:23.569 31835-31835/com.example.adminclases.appsensor W/art: 
Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 


android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter
(android.
graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, 
android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
would have incorrectly overridden the package-
private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-05 20:05:23.734 31835-31865/com.example.adminclases.appsensor 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
12-05 20:05:23.740 31835-31835/com.example.adminclases.appsensor D/Atlas: 
Validating map...
12-05 20:05:23.804 31835-31865/com.example.adminclases.appsensor I/Adreno-
EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: 


 AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C4.05.00.02.094.015_msm8916_64_refs/tags/
 AU_LINUX_
 ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C4.05.00.02.094.015__release_AU (I68fa98814b)

OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.02

Build Date: 07/16/15 Thu

Local Branch: 

Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C4.05.00.02.094.015

Local Patches: NONE

Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
12-05 20:05:23.804 31835-31865/com.example.adminclases.appsensor 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-05 20:05:23.817 31835-31865/com.example.adminclases.appsensor 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-05 20:05:23.950 31835-31835/com.example.adminclases.appsensor I/Timeline: 
Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3338690f time:843740706
```

Comment: Intenta abriendo el logCat a ver que dice.

Comment: Puedes agregar el log de errores a la hora de seleccionar una fila. Ayuda muchisimo ver en el log porque se genera la excepción que tira abajo una actividad.

Comment: ahi agregue el logcat

Comment: @xander no logras recibir los datos o en realidad tienes un error que cierra la app? Lo que agregas como LogCat no es de ayuda, busca donde diga "Caused by".

Comment: @ Jorgesys♦ es que no se cierra la app, se pone en blanco y vuelve a un activity atras que se llama ActivityIngreso, nose porque si en ningun momento la relaciono con esa app o eso veo hasta ahora y no me salen errores adjunto video https://youtu.be/kcV2BpfRueE

Comment: @xander desde el listado das click y te lleva a otra Activity en la cual se deben llenar los EditText con los valores, ¿es así ?

Comment: @Jorgesys♦  correcto, pero al momento de dar el click se va a otra activity como se logra ver en el video

Comment: @xander te puedo asegurar que el envió y la recepción se realiza correctamente, pero veo no aparecen en los editText los valores.

Comment: @xander Porque en el video tu Activity modificar tienes botones Registrar y Lista y en el layout se llaman Modificar y Eliminar?

Comment: @Jorgesys♦ es otra activity, en esa es donde agrego items a la lista, no la agregue porque segun creo no se relaciona con el problema, pero por algun motivo me lleva atras

Comment: Agrega el manifiesto a la pregunta por favor. Y en ultima instancia sube el proyecto a Github para tener un panorama claro y completo del código.

Answer (score 0):

el error me suena a que tu activity modificar no se está creando de manera correcta, puede que estes haciendo alguna referencia nula, en tu activity Modificar, intenta cambiando estás lineas de código

```
 if(b!=null)
     { id_recibe=b.getInt("ID"); 
       nombre_recibe=b.getString("NOMBRE"); 
       usuario_recibe=b.getString("USUARIO"); 
       password_recibe=b.getString("PASSWORD"); 
       correo_recibe=b.getString("CORREO"); 
      } 
ed_nombre.setText(nombre_recibe); 
ed_usuario.setText(usuario_recibe); 
ed_password.setText(password_recibe); 
ed_correo.setText(correo_recibe);
```

por estas:

```
 if(b!=null)
     { id_recibe=b.getInt("ID"); 
       nombre_recibe=b.getString("NOMBRE"); 
       usuario_recibe=b.getString("USUARIO"); 
       password_recibe=b.getString("PASSWORD"); 
       correo_recibe=b.getString("CORREO"); 

       ed_nombre.setText(nombre_recibe); 
       ed_usuario.setText(usuario_recibe); 
       ed_password.setText(password_recibe); 
       ed_correo.setText(correo_recibe);
      }
```

Es posible que algunos de los valores que estás mandando através del Intent sea nulo, por lo que nunca inicializa alguna de esas variables, entonces al momento de ponerla en un edittext, es nula y tu activity se crashea.

Comment: El error continua, no cambio en nada al parecer  :/

Comment: En tu logcat podrías escribir en el filtro la palabra "exception", solo para verificar si se manda alguna exception

Comment: El envío y recepción de datos es correcto, a que te refieres con " activity modificar no se está creando de manera correcta", como no se podría estar creando correctamente?

Comment: no manda ninguna exception

Comment: me refería a que en el método onCreate() es probable que haya un crash, pero al parecer no hay exception. Si pudieras mandarme el String que genera tu método ListaPersonas(), puedo ayudarte a resolver tu error.

Comment: va a generar un String en relacion a lo que este cargado en la base de datos, ese metodo llena la lista

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes llamar el método cargar listado desde `onCreate()` y no uses `onPostResume()` :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            int id = Integer.parseInt(listado.get(i).split(" ")[0]);
            String nombre=listado.get(i).split(" ")[1];
            String usuario=listado.get(i).split(" ")[2];
            String password=listado.get(i).split(" ")[3];
            String correo=listado.get(i).split(" ")[4];
            Intent intent=new Intent(Listado.this,Modificar.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID",id);
            intent.putExtra("NOMBRE",nombre);
            intent.putExtra("USUARIO",usuario);
            intent.putExtra("PASSWORD",password);
            intent.putExtra("CORREO",correo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     cargarlistado();
}

/*@Override
protected void onPostResume () {
    super.onPostResume();
    cargarlistado();
}*/
```

Comment: ♦ El error se mantiene :/ no entiendo porque esta fallando, quizas me falto algo que agregar, aca esta mi proyecto por si nesesitas mas detalles
https://www.sendspace.com/file/11o6pl